# Login to OmniAuth GAFYD authenticated website through Android HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient, omniauth

I'm writing an Android app that needs to programatically connect to Ruby on Rails website that uses the OmniAuth gem for login.  The authentication provider is a Google Apps For Your Domain site.

I think what I need to do is to pass login information to the GAFYD url, get a key or token back and somehow pass that to the original website I need to make requests from.

Does anyone know how I need to configure HttpClient to do this?